# Angular $Scope Object run before the Jquery get method finish getting the data?

Tags: jquery, xml, json, angularjs, get

i have this code to get the xml data and convert it to json finally assign the json to the $scope object to be handled by the view

```
function employeesList($scope) {
    $.get('http://www.benisuef.gov.eg/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=%7B9E8B17D5-7AE8-4BC8-9068-105DA949734A%7D&XMLDATA=TRUE', function(xml) {
        var json = $.xml2json(xml, true);
        $scope.employeeList = json.data[0].row;
    });
}
```

the problem is the angular controller doesn't wait until the get finish its work 
how can i make it wait for that ??!

Comment: **A** JAX is called so because it is **asynchronous**

Comment: You souldn't use jQuery Ajax but Angularjs $http method.

Answer (score 1):

If I started to use `Angular`, I would  write all module in Angular (less issues). As you know Angular `$http` returns `promise` like callback in jQuery.

You can read this [link](http://urish.org/angular/AngularPromises.pdf) how promises work.

BTW, you can write something like

```
$scope.employeeList = $http.get('http://www.benisuef.gov.eg/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=%7B9E8B17D5-7AE8-4BC8-9068-105DA949734A%7D&XMLDATA=TRUE')).then(
   function(result) {
     var json = $.xml2json(result.data, true);

   return json.data[0].row;
  });
```

some debugger:

```
<pre>{{employeeList  | json}}</pre>
```